# Callback or Generator to handle specific parts of a repetitive chunk of code?

Tags: python, callback, generator

I have a bunch of logic that repeats several times in different parts of an API where almost everything is the same, except one additional job sometimes has to be done, and is never the same.

To be clear, here is the "shape" of what is happening:

```py
do_some_preparation()
for item in iterable:
    do_several_things_that_are_always_the_same()
    maybe_do_something_specific()
    # where the specific part requires:
    #   - context from the loop
    #   - context from where the whole action is started
```

I see 2 possible design patterns to solve this: callback or generator.

#### Callback

```py
def handle_the_thing(..., callback=None):
    do_some_preparation()
    for item in iterable:
        do_several_things_that_are_always_the_same()
        if callback:
            callback(loop_context)

# case with no specific action
handle_the_thing(...)

# case with some specific action
def do_thing_A(): ...
handle_the_thing(..., do_thing_A)

# case with another specific action
def do_thing_B(): ...
handle_the_thing(..., do_thing_B)
```

#### Generator

```py
def handle_the_thing(...):
    do_some_preparation()
    for item in iterable:
        do_several_things_that_are_always_the_same()
        yield loop_context

# case with no specific action
for _ in handle_the_thing(...):
    pass

# case with some specific action
for var_from_loop in handle_the_thing(...):
    # do your thing A

# case with another specific action
for var_from_loop in handle_the_thing(...):
    # do your thing B
```

**So question is, which one is the most pythonic and maintainable/correct?**

**Is there even another way to approach this problem?**

Keep in mind all those things are pretty dependent and I couldn't easily extract each part in its own function.
I bother with this because there are some complex actions that are all related in the common part, and I'd rather avoid having to maintain them in several places.

Personally, I see advantages in both cases, but I guess generators are more versatile.
Only thing is... the case with no special action seems a bit finicky. But maybe it's a common pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Your insight is exactly right. **Generators seem to be the way to go.**

To fix how weird the no special action case looks, I would add a `yield_contexts` parameter to `handle_the_thing`.

```py
def handle_the_thing(..., yield_contexts=True):
    do_some_preparation()
    for item in iterable:
        do_several_things_that_are_always_the_same()
        if yield_contexts:
            yield loop_context

# case with no specific action -> CLEANER!
handle_the_thing(..., yield_contexts=False)

# case with some specific action -> IDENTICAL!
for var_from_loop in handle_the_thing(...):
    # do your thing A
```